# Can't start Phonegap IOS server app, Can't run phonegap with Xcode, Can't fine Phonegap files for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app, phonegap-cli

So I'm trying to learn to building some IOS apps. I downloaded the Phonegap desktop app and created a project. I installed the ios app on my phone to view the project. The server port URL is wrong and the project doesn't download. I tried everything I changed the port number, Used my IP address from terminal and my browser, used my routers IP, and didn't use a router at all. Nothing works and the newest info I found online is from a year ago and apparently this is a bug that never got fixed. What do I do now?

So I downloaded xcode. I'm trying to run xcode with phonegap together. Everything online says to download "the latest phonegap working files". Of course there are no files to download on the phonegap site. just the desktop app.

I Went over to Adobe phonegap build. It said the same thing download "the latest phonegap working files". There are no files to download though.

I even tried installing phonegap with `$ sudo npm install -g phonegap`. But I keep getting "Command not found". I do have NPM and node installed.

I cant believe how little Phonegap documentation There is and whats out there seems out dated. Does anyone have any advice how I can get phonegap working oneway or another? This is ridiculous.

- OS X El Capitan 10.11.2
- Xcode v:7.2.1
- Phonegap desktop app v:0.2.1
- iPhone 5 v:8.4.1
- My fire wall is NOT on. So its not that - BTW.

Comment: My fire wall is NOT on so its not that BTW.

Comment: You can also try at [Nitobi forum for Phonegap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi) Even though this is technically CLI, the "official forum" sometimes has answers. FWIW: which page did you take directions from?

Comment: Why do you use phonegap and not cordova?

Comment: +1 on running with cordova. You can do a quick test app by following the download / create instructions here: https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted. Christophe Coenraets has a longer tutorial up here: https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/.